# LiveData Coroutine Constructor must be initialized in LiveData Switchmap error

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

I have the following code, that shows no syntax error on Android Studio

```
    val liveData: LiveData<String> =
        Transformations.switchMap(repository.liveData) {
            liveData {
                withContext(IO) {
                    emit(it.toString().padStart(8, '0'))
                }
            }
        }
```

However, during compilation, it errors out stating

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but LiveData<TypeVariable(Y)!>! was expected
Variable 'liveData' must be initialized
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public operator fun <T, R> DeepRecursiveFunction<TypeVariable(T), TypeVariable(R)>.invoke(value: TypeVariable(T)): TypeVariable(R) defined in kotlin
```

What's the error here?

Comment: Have you tried renaming your `val liveData` to some other name than the exact same name as the `liveData` method?

Comment: Thanks @ianhanniballake. I found out the reason why. I think it's a mixture of Android Studio + git bug. What I did is I git reset my code to its origin, i.e. the build.gradle dependency ` implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0"` was reset as well. Android Studio didn't warn of the missing library. I can still Option+Click the `liveData` and see the code. But the compiler cannot access the code anymore. So error out. All I need to do is to include back the library, and it now works.